# can someone tell what this code snippet does

Tags: linux, perl, shell, variables, environment

I am trying to understand this below mentioned code snippet, currently i am stuck at line number 3 and after digging alot i got to know that $MYPERL is where perl binaries are defined/located and for $PERLDB is what perl debugger i,e -d:ptkdb and basically this is a perl script and some how person who coded this wrapps it to use the latest perl version. can some one tell me how i can change MYPERL variable value /home/Desktop/goudar/perl/ and execute rest of the script ?

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- cperl -*-
exec $MYPERL -x $PERLDB -wS $0 ${1+"$@"}
#!perl
#line 6

### perl 
use Cwd;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw/ uniq /;
use JSON;
use Mojo::JSON;

#rest of the code go here#
```

Comment: It's all explained in [perlrun](https://p3rl.org/perlrun)

Comment: @Borodin did you know that from using it, or did you go hunting? I've never fully read that page before.

Comment: @simbabque: I make a point of reading through all of the documentation at least once year. You would be surprised what you can find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *can someone tell what this code snippet does*

It executes the embedded Perl script using the Perl interpreter specified by env var `MYPERL`. Options specified in env var `PERLDB` (if any) are passed to the interpreter. Warnings are enabled globally.

> *how i can change MYPERL variable value /home/Desktop/goudar/perl/ and execute rest of the script*

If the process that will launch the script is a bourne-based, then

```
export MYPERL=/home/Desktop/goudar/perl/
```

That said, I don't know why you want to assign that value to the `MYPERL` env variable since the script expects it to be the path to a Perl interpreter.